# Android "Permission Denial"

Tags: android

I have been working on an Android 2.2 app for the past three months, but decided this past week to try to build the app using Android 2.1 SDK. The app ran fine under 2.2 in the emulator, and I was able to build the source as a 2.1 project successfully, but when I try to run the app in the 2.1 emulator, I get the following runtime error:

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.tampamobileapps.testapp/.LoginScreen } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires null

The app is not that complicated and only makes HTTP POST and GET requests. It also supports PayPal payments, but this API worked fine under 2.2. I have googled this error message and have not found any solutions to get rid of the error.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:**

Here's the relevant parts of the Android manifest; the `LoginScreen` currently does nothing of consequence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.app"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
      android:debuggable="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:name=".SharedApplicationContext">

        <activity android:name=".LoginScreen"
          android:label="@string/login_screen_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>                    
        <activity android:name=".LoginScreen"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainMenu"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please show us the permissions you currently have in your existing manifest.xml.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: Looks like the right permissions.  Can you post your whole manifest and the code for your LoginScreen Activity?

Comment: We need to see intent-filter from manifest. Does it set? For android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.category.LAUNCHER at least.

Answer (score 6):

You have duplicate activities defined in your manifest for `.LoginScreen`.  Try removing:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginScreen"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the android:exported="true" option.

For instance, preference activities in live wallpapers need this set. Hope this helps someone else as I know you have probably already sorted the issue.